# ADO.NET Entity Framework multiple FK in one table

Tags: foreign-keys, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm using a code from a tutorial to try things out that I'll need in my real project. I have a table in my `DataBase` with a lot (16) `Foreign Keys` in it I have to recreate the whole `DataBase` using `ADO.NET EF` and now I'm little stuck with this particular case. Here is the code that I'm using for testing purposes:

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        //public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

        //public int BlogId1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog1 { get; set; }

        //public int BlogId2 { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog2 { get; set; }

        //public int BlogId3 { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog3 { get; set; }

        //public int BlogId4 { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog4 { get; set; }
    }
```

I've commented the `int` properties as it seems that I don't need them. Executing this code I get the following:

[image]

So there are two thing that concerns me at the moment - is this the way to add multiple `Foreign Keys` at one table and if so - the two rows underlined with red - why I have `Blog_BlogId` and `Blog_BlogId1` before I get the expected `Blog1_.., Blog2_...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I lost the post here from where I got the solution but in this particular case it seems to be some sort of naming convention I have to uncomment the commented code and change the names without using numbers or underscore.  Then in `OnModelCreating` event add this code as many times as I need :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(c => c.Blog)
                                  .WithMany(m => m.Posts)
                                  .HasForeignKey(c => c.BlogId)
                                  .WillCascadeOnDelete();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(c => c.Blogged)
                                          .WithMany()
                                          .HasForeignKey(c => c.BloggedId)
                                          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Notice that I change the property name and the class instance name every time I add new record for foreign key.